# How Can I get This PHP Registration Script Using PDO Prepared Statements/Positional Placeholders To Run?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a PHP registration script using PDO prepared statements with positional placeholders. But the MySQL queries don't execute. `var_dump();` doesn't display any error.

I desperately need someone to closely look at my code and explain to me why the queries don't execute.

Below is a rewrite of **register.php**, which now displays errors, if certain, predefined conditions are not met. However, it doesn't display any error, when the insert or select query fail. var_dump(); doesn't display any error either, even though PDO queries fail to execute.

Please, I need your help to fix this. Your time and input are much appreciated in advance. Thanks.

**register.php:**

```
<?php

    // include configuration file
    require ("includes/config.php");
    
    //Class import for image uploading
    //classes is the map where the class file is stored (one above the root)
    include ("classes/upload/upload_class.php");
    
    
       // define variables and set to empty values
       $firstnameErr = $lastnameErr = $usernameErr = $genderErr = $passwordErr = $confirmationErr = $emailErr = $birthdayErr = $phoneErr = "";
      $firstname = $lastname = $username = $gender = $password = $confirmation = $email = $birthday = $phone = "";
         
    // if form was submitted
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        
        $firstname = student_input($_POST["firstname"]);
        $lastname = student_input($_POST["lastname"]);
        $username = student_input($_POST["username"]);
        $gender = student_input($_POST["gender"]);
        $password = student_input($_POST["password"]);
        $confirmation = student_input($_POST["confirmation"]);
        $email = student_input($_POST["email"]);
        $birthday = student_input($_POST["birthday"]);
        $phone = student_input($_POST["phone"]);
                
        // validate submission
        if (empty($_POST["firstname"]))
        {
            $firstnameErr = "First name is required.";
        }
        else
        {
               $firstname = student_input($_POST["firstname"]);
        }
        if(empty($_POST["lastname"]))
        {
            $lastnameErr = "Last name is required.";
        }
        else
        {
               $lastname = student_input($_POST["lastname"]);
        }
        if(empty($_POST["username"]))
        {
            $usernameErr = "Username is required.";
        }
        else if(!empty($_POST["username"]))
        { 
            // validate username
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username))
            {
                $usernameErr = "Username must contain only letters and numbers.";
            }
            if (strlen($username) < 4 || strlen($username) > 10)
            {
                $usernameErr = "Username must be from 4 to 10 characters.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
               $username = student_input($_POST["username"]);
        }
        if(empty($_POST["gender"]))
        {
            $genderErr = "Gender is required.";
        }
        else
        {
               $gender = student_input($_POST["gender"]);
        }
        if(empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            $passwordErr = "Enter a password.";
        }
        else if(!empty($_POST["password"]))
        {           
            // validate username
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $password))
            {
                $passwordErr = "Password must contain letters, numbers and special characters.";
            }
            if (strlen($password) < 8 || strlen($password) > 20)
            {
                $passwordErr = "Password must be from 8 to 20 characters.";
            }
        }
        else if (empty($_POST["confirmation"]))
        {
            $confirmationErr = "Confirm your password.";
        }
        else if ($_POST["password"] != $_POST["confirmation"])
        {
            $confirmationErr = "Password and confirmation don't match.";
        }
        else
        {
            $password = student_input($_POST["password"]);
        }
        if(empty($_POST["email"]))
        {
            $emailErr = "Your email address is required.";
        }
        else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
        }
        else
        {
             $email = student_input($_POST["email"]);
        }
        if(empty($_POST["birthday"]))
        {
            $birthdayErr = "Birthday is required.";
        }
        else if(!empty($_POST["birthday"]))
        {
               $today = date("d-m-Y");
               $diff = date_diff(date_create($birthday), date_create($today));

               if($diff->format('%y%') < 6)
               {
                   $birthdayErr = "You must be at least 6 years old to register.";
               }
               else
               {
                  $birthday = student_input($_POST["birthday"]);                   
               }
        }
        if(empty($_POST["phone"]))
        {
            $phoneErr = "Phone number is required.";
        }
        else if(!empty($_POST["phone"]))
        {           
            // Don't allow country codes to be included (assumes a leading "+") 
            if (preg_match('/^(\+)[\s]*(.*)$/',$phone))
            {
                $phoneErr = "You should not include the country code.";
            }
            // Remove hyphens - they are not part of a telephone number
            $phone = str_replace ('-', '', $phone);
  
            // Now check that all the characters are digits
            if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10,11}$/',$phone))
            {
                $phoneErr = "Phone number should be either 10 or 11 digits";
            } 
  
            // Now check that the first digit is 0
            if (!preg_match('/^0[0-9]{9,10}$/',$phone))
            {
                $phoneErr = "The telephone number should start with a 0";
            }
            else
            {           
               $phone = student_input($_POST["phone"]);
            }
        }
        else if(!empty($_FILES["userimage"]))
        {
            //This is the directory where images will be saved 
            $max_size = 1024*250; // the max. size for uploading
    
            $my_upload = new file_upload;

            $my_upload->upload_dir = "images/user/"; // "files" is the folder for the uploaded files (you have to create this folder)
            $my_upload->extensions = array(".png", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg"); // specify the allowed extensions here
            // $my_upload->extensions = "de"; // use this to switch the messages into an other language (translate first!!!)
            $my_upload->max_length_filename = 50; // change this value to fit your field length in your database (standard 100)
            $my_upload->rename_file = false;
        
            $my_upload->the_temp_file = $_FILES['userimage']['tmp_name'];
            $my_upload->the_file = $_FILES['userimage']['name'];
            $my_upload->http_error = $_FILES['userimage']['error'];
            $my_upload->replace = "y";
            $my_upload->do_filename_check = "n"; // use this boolean to check for a valid filename
         if ($my_upload->upload()) // new name is an additional filename information, use this to rename the uploaded file
            {
                $full_path = $my_upload->upload_dir.$my_upload->file_copy;
                $imagename = $my_upload->file_copy;
             }
             else
             {
                 $imagename = "";
             }
        }
        else
        { 
            try
            {   
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
            $stmt->execute(student_input($_POST["username"]));
            $user = $stmt->fetch(); # get users data
            
            if($user["username"]==$username)
            {
                $errorMsg[]="Sorry username already exists"; //check condition username already exists
            }
            else if($user["email"]==$email)
            {
                $errorMsg[]="Sorry email already exists"; //check condition email already exists 
            }
            else if($user["phone"]==$phone)
            {
                $errorMsg[]="Sorry, the phone number already exists"; //check condition email already exists 
            }
            else if(!isset($errorMsg)) //check no "$errorMs g" show then continue
            {
                $new_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //encrypt password using password_hash()
            
               // insert form input into database
                $stmt= $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, gender, password, email, birthday, phone, userimage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")->execute($data);
            
               // find out user's ID
               $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS user_id");
               $user_id = $stmt[0]["user_id"];
            
               // redirect to list users page
               header("Location: userinfo.php");
            }
         }
                catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }       
    
    }
}
        // render the header template
        include("templates/header.php");
        
        // render add user template
        include("templates/register-form.php");
    
       // render the footer template
       include("templates/footer.php");
?>
```

I have the following, relevant code in **functions.php**, which is called by the **config.php**:

```
// validate user input
function student_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Another thing: how do I print the errors on the register-form.php right below any existing error's input field?

**register-form.php:**

```html
<br>
<br>
<h1>Register</h1>
<br>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name:</label><span class ="error">*</span> <input autofocus class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text"/>
            <span class = "error"><?php //echo $errorMsg["firstname"];?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name:</label><span class ="error">*</span> <input class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text"/><br />
            <span class = "error"><?php //echo $errorMsg["lastname"];?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username:</label><span class ="error">*</span> <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text"/><br />
            <span class = "error"><?php //echo $errorMsg["username"];?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Gender:</label><span class ="error">*</span> <select class="form-control" name="gender" value="gender">
                <option value="">Select your gender</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select><br />
            <span class = "error"><?php //echo $error;?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label><span class ="error">*</span> <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password"/ autocomplete="off"><br />
            <span class = "error"><?php //echo $error;?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password:</label><span class ="error">*</span> <input class="form-control" name="confirmation" type="password"/><br />
            <span class = "error"><?php //echo $error;?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email:</label><span class ="error">*</span> <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text"/><br />
            <span class = "error"><?php //echo $error;?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone:</label><span class ="error">*</span> <input class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" type="tel" min="10" max="11"/><br />
            <span class = "error"><?php //echo $error;?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date of Birth:</label><span class ="error"></span> <input class="form-control" name="birthday" placeholder="birthday" type="date" /><br />
            <span class = "error"><?php //echo $error[birthday];?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Passport Photo:</label><input class="form-control" name="userimage" id="fileimage" placeholder="Your Photo" type="file"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Register" value="Register">Register</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div>
    or <a href="login.php">Login</a>
</div>
<br/>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: You use `$stmt->execute(` twice on the insert, is this meant to happen?

Comment: @NigelRen, I wasn't aware that $stmt->execute( cannot be used twice like that. How do I rewrite the second line of code? - `if ($stmt->execute([$firstname, $lastname, $username, $gender, $password, $email, $birthday, $phone, $imagename]))`